# What is the standard method to numpy extension create modules that support different array datatypes?

Tags: numpy, python-c-api

Assuming I have a C function I would like to wrap by the Nympy(Python)-C API to create a Python extension module. This module should be capable of accepting Numpy array that can have multiple types such as np.double, np.single, np.long, np.short etc.

What is the standard way to implement it? I assume that switch-case with a separate implementation for each of the types is not maintainable and there is a proper alternative

Comment: The numpy C code is heavily preprocessed. I don't know what all it it does, but may include compiling versions for different dtypes.

Comment: I started to write an answer and then found the Numpy documentation already (mostly) answer this : https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/c-info.how-to-extend.html